# Making Verbs Nouns in German

Tags: noun

As we all know, folks, in English we can make any verb a noun by adding -ing and use it as a subject or object.

My question is as follows: In German, how to I do that? How am I supposed to translate the following sentences into German?

1. Helping your parents is an important thing to do.
2. Growing cacti is an interesting thing to do.

Comment: In none of the examples one would need substantivation, since better words are available 1) *Unterstützung* 2) *Zucht*.

Comment: *The growing of cacti* has a noun, *growing cacti* a verb.

Comment: @DavidVogt That was my first impulse, too, but English grammar does seem to see these ("gerunds") as nouns in both cases. https://www.englisch-hilfen.de/grammar/gerund.htm https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/american_english/gerund

Comment: @HalvarF I follow the reasoning elaborated here: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/229227/331821.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple ways to make a verb a subject or object in German as well as in English.

English:

> **The taming of the shrew** is a goal of some protagonists in a famous Shakespeare play.
> **Taming the shrew** is ...
> **To tame the shrew** is ...

German equivalents are:

1. Making the infinitve a noun ("Substantivierung"):

> **Das Züchten von Kakteen** ist ein interessantes Hobby.
> **Züchten von Kakteen** ist ...

2. Infinitive with "zu":

> **Kakteen zu züchten** ist ein interessantes Hobby.

3. Using an equivalent full noun.

> **Die Zucht von Kakteen** ist ein interessantes Hobby.

Often these full nouns have been derived from the verb at some point by using the suffix -ung or rules from their original languages:

> *Fehler beheben* => Die **Behebung** von Fehlern
> *Software installieren* => Die **Installation** von Software

In all of these sentences, the grammatical subject of the sentence is what comes before "ist".

Answer (score 1):

The general rule is: take the infinitive form and use an uppercase starting letter:

> (Das) Lesen ist ein schöner Zeitvertreib.

Frequently differently formed sustantives already exist as:

> - bilden -> Bildung
> - unterstützen -> Unterstützung